# Parse Time PT##H##M to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I could do this by breaking string using substrings but there should be some way to parse string of specific format and get out the desired values.

Please help me if there is any other easy and elegant way to do this.

[Update]
This is how I'm doing using substrings:

```
NSRange ptRange = [timeString rangeOfString:@"T"];
NSRange hRange = [timeString rangeOfString:@"H"];
NSRange mRange = [timeString rangeOfString:@"M"];

NSString *hours = nil;
if (hRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    hours = [timeString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(ptRange.location+ptRange.length, hRange.location-(ptRange.location+ptRange.length))];
}
else {
    hRange = ptRange;
}

NSString *minutes = nil;
if (mRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    minutes = [timeString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(hRange.location+hRange.length, mRange.location-(hRange.location+hRange.length))];
}
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate*date = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",hours.integerValue,minutes.integerValue]];
```

Comment: Show what attempt you have made using `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Why do all the string processing? Just specify a date format that matches the original string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now my implementation is the answer for this question

```
NSRange ptRange = [timeString rangeOfString:@"T"];
NSRange hRange = [timeString rangeOfString:@"H"];
NSRange mRange = [timeString rangeOfString:@"M"];

NSString *hours = nil;
if (hRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    hours = [timeString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(ptRange.location+ptRange.length, hRange.location-(ptRange.location+ptRange.length))];
}
else {
    hRange = ptRange;
}

NSString *minutes = nil;
if (mRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    minutes = [timeString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(hRange.location+hRange.length, mRange.location-(hRange.location+hRange.length))];
}
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate*date = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",hours.integerValue,minutes.integerValue]];
```